# Strange assignment in implementing strtok

Tags: c

I am studying the implementation of `strtok` and have a question. On this line, `s [-1] = 0`, I don't understand how `tok` is limited to the first token since we had previously assigned it everything contained in `s`.

```
char *strtok(char *s, const char *delim)
{
    static char *last;

    return strtok_r(s, delim, &last);
}

char *strtok_r(char *s, const char *delim, char **last)
{
    char *spanp;
    int c, sc;
    char *tok;

    if (s == NULL && (s = *last) == NULL)
        return (NULL);

    tok = s;
    for (;;) {
        c = *s++;
        spanp = (char *)delim;
        do {
            if ((sc = *spanp++) == c) {
                if (c == 0)
                    s = NULL;
                else
                    s[-1] = 0;
                *last = s;
                return (tok);
            }
        } while (sc != 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: While I had trouble understand the original question. uuser3780071 does bring up a good point. where it says "s[-1] = 0; *last = s;" what is it doing? I was under the impression that accessing a negative index always gave you an index out of bounds error. but if array s was shifted, this apparently isn't the case?

Comment: `s[-1] = 0;` is equivalent to `*(s - 1) = '\0';`, so it simply sets the location just before where `s` is pointing to zero. Recall that `s[i]` is just another way of writing `*(s + n)`.

Comment: @ooga Right, but I just didn't think it was possible to access a negative index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This took much more space than I anticipated when I started, but I think it offers a useful explanation along with the others. (it became more of a mission really)

**NOTE:** This combination of `strtok` and `strtok_r` attempt to provide a reentrant implementation of the usual `strtok` from `string.h` by saving the address of the `last` character as a static variable in `strtok`. (whether it is reentrant was not tested)

The easiest way to understand this code (at least for me) is to understand what `strtok` and `strtok_r` do with the string they are operating on. Here `strtok_r` is where the work is done. `strtok_r` basically assigns a pointer to the string provided as an argument and then **'inch-worms'** down the string, character-by-character, comparing each character to a delimiter character or null terminating character.

The key is to understand that the job of `strtok_r` is to chop the string up into separate tokens, which are returned on successive calls to the function. How does it work? The string is broken up into separate tokens by replacing each delimiter character found in the original string with a null-terminating character and returning a pointer to the beginning of the token (which will either be the start of the string on first call, or the **next-character after the last delimiter** on successive calls)

As with the `string.h strtok` function, the first call to `strtok` takes the original string as the first argument. For successive parsing of the same string `NULL` is used as the first argument. The original string is left littered with null-terminating characters after calls to `strtok`, so make a copy if you need it further. Below is an explanation of what goes on in `strtok_r` as you **inch-worm** down the string.

Consider for example the following string and `strtok_r`:

```
'this is a test'
```

**The outer for loop stepping through string `s`**

(ignoring the assignments and the `NULL` tests, the function assigns `tok` a pointer to the beginning of the string (`tok = s`). It then enters the for loop where it will step through string `s` one character at a time. `c` is assigned the (int value of) the current character pointed to by 's', and the pointer for `s` in incremented to the next character (this is the **for loop increment of 's'**). `spanp` is assigned the pointer to the delimiter array.

**The inner do loop stepping though the delimeters 'delim'**

The do loop is entered and then, using the `spanp` pointer, proceeds to go through the `delim` array testing if `sc` (the `spanp` character) equals the current for loop character `c`. If and only if our character `c` matches a delimiter, we then encounter the confusing `if (c == 0)` `if-then-else` test.

**The `if (c == 0)` `if-then-else` test**

This test is actually simple to understand when you think about it. As we are crawling down string `s` checking each character against the `delim` array. If we match one of the delimiters or hit the end, then what? We are about to return from the function, so what must we do?

Here we ask, did we reach the normal end of the string `(c == 0)`, if so we set `s = NULL`, otherwise we match a delimiter, but are not at the end of the string.

**Here is where the magic happens**. We need to replace the delimiter character in the string with a null-terminating character (either `0` or `'\0'`). Why not set the pointer `s = 0` here? Answer: we can't, we incremented it assigning `c = *s++;` at the beginning of the for loop, so **`s` is now pointing to the next character in the string rather than the delimiter**. So in order to replace the delimiter in string `s` with a null-terminating character, we must do `s[-1] = 0;` This is where the string `s` gets chopped into a token. `last` is assigned the address of the current pointer `s` and `tok` (pointing to the original beginning of `s`) is returned by the function.

So, in the main program, you how have the return of `strtok_r` which is a pointer pointing to the first character in the string `s` you passed to `strtok_r` which is now null-terminated at the first occurrence of the matching character in `delim` providing you with the token from the original string `s` you asked for.

Answer (score 2):

`tok` was not previously assigned "everything contained in `s`". It was set to point to the same address as the address in `s`.

The `s[-1] = 0;` line is equivalent to `*(s - 1) = '\0';`, which sets the location just before where `s` is pointing to zero.

By setting that location to zero, returning the current value of `tok` will point to a string whose data spans from `tok` to `s - 2` and is properly null-terminated at `s - 1`.

Also note that before `tok` is returned, `*last` is set to the current value of `s`, which is the starting scan position for the next token. `strtok` saves this value in a static variable so it can be remembered and automatically used for the next token.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses, according to what I understood the statement s [-1] points to where the delimiter character then override it for null character is found, do not understand how this can happen I have followed the execution of the program in the debugger and I see that in every execution of c = * s + + the characters are moving in these positions s [-1] s [-2] s [-3] and so susesivamente not understand this?

Note: excuse the spelling is that I use a translator

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to reach the statement `return(tok);`. One way is that at the point where `tok = s;` occurs, `s` contains none of the delimiter characters (contents of `delim`).
That means `s` is a single token.  The `for` loop ends when `c == 0`, that is, at the
null byte at the end of `s`, and `strtok_r` returns `tok` (that is,
the entire string that was in `s` at the time of `tok = s;`), as it should.

The other way for that return statement to occur is when `s` contains some character
that is in `delim`. In that case, at some point `*spanp == c` will be true where
`*spanp` is not  the terminating null of `delim`, and therefore `c == 0` is false.
At this point, `s` points to the character *after* the one from which `c` was read,
and `s - 1` points to the place where the delimiter was found. 
The statement `s[-1] = 0;` overwrites the delimiter with a null character, so now
`tok` points to a string of characters that starts where `tok = s;` said to start,
and ends at the first delimiter that was found in that string.  In other words,
`tok` now points to the first token in that string, no more and no less,
and it is correctly returned by the function.

The code is not very well self-documenting in my opinion, so it is understandable
that it is confusing.